# Running csh from inside C

Tags: c, exec, csh

I want to run from my C program a `csh` command. I did this using the following code:

```
char *csh_command[3];
...
csh_command[2]=(char*)malloc((length_command+strlen("\"\""))*sizeof(char));

csh_command[0]=(char*)malloc((strlen("-f")+1)*sizeof(char));
csh_command[1]=(char*)malloc((strlen("-c")+1)*sizeof(char));

strcat (csh_command[0],"-f");
strcat (csh_command[1],"-c");
strcat (csh_command[2],"\"");
strcat (csh_command[2],full_command);
strcat (csh_command[2],"\"");
pid=fork();
if (pid == 0){
        execvp("csh", csh_command);
}
```

what I do here is creating an array containing the parameters for `csh`:
-f, -c, "[the command to run]"

But the result is not what expected. The child process just runs in the background without doing anything.

We've tried to run `ls | wc -l` using it.

where is the problem?

**EDIT:**

The `length_command` variable already has a +1 for `\0`. The problem was with the array not terminated in `NULL`. And the `"` were unnecessary.

Comment: Please don't write about not casting the result of `malloc`. I'm aware of this, and still choose to do it.

Comment: I thought the argument array passed to execvp had to end with a `NULL` pointer?

Comment: Does `csh_command` has the string you expected to have ? `sizeof(char)` is 1 and so there is no need to multiply it in `malloc` ?

Comment: fork doesn't return the pid. fork returns a value based on where it is. 0 = child > 0 = parent. to get the pid use pid = getpid(). Just use execvp with a null terminated pointer at the end of the array

Comment: @Tanner, `fork` return the pid of the child for the father, and 0 for the child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First error I see it that

> The array of  pointers must be
>   terminated by a NULL pointer.

Try:

```
char *csh_command[4];
csh_command[3] = 0;
```

And what is the `length_command` value? it should be at least `strlen(full_command)+1`

**UPDATE:**

Another issue could be related to `strcat`, because you are using not initialized strings and they can contain some garbage. Do at least following:

```
char *str = (char *)malloc(strlen("blabla")+1);
str[0] = '\0';
strcat(str, "blabla");
```

Or just use `strdup` instead of `malloc`+`strcat`

Answer (score 2):

A few issues that make your code more complex and incorrect than it has to be:

- `malloc()` + `strcat()` = `strdup()`
- Unless you are planning on having a generic `cshcmd()` function or something, why are you copying the string literals instead of using them directly?
- The `execvp()` argument array must end with a `NULL`.
- Array initializers and anonymous arrays are a blessing in cases like this - you would probably not miss the NULL at the end with them. Unless, of course, you have to use fully dynamic structures...
- You should not have those extra double quotes in the command argument. Those are intended for the running shell when you use the command line and are stripped away when calling `exec()`. In other words, `csh` should see `ls -1 | wc -l`, not `"ls -1 | wc -l"`.
- Oh, and the first element of the argument array in `exec()` is always `argv[0]`. That should probably be something along the lines `csh`, not an option.

EDIT:

- One more thing: Do you clear the memory allocated by `malloc()` before using `strcat()`?  `strcat()` will happily overflow your buffer, depending on whatever random contents it already has...

Answer (score 1):

First issue is you have an off-by-one error in your malloc - there's no room for the terminating null (`\0')

```
length_command + strlen("\"\"") + 1
```

Second issue is with `execvp`:

> The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer.

In addition, `execvp()` uses a shell and searches your path for the given command. The first argument where you have `"csh"` currently is the executable you want to run. You talk about wanting to run `wc`; that would be the first argument.